# why does -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 has no effect in my compilation?

Tags: gcc, c++17, fortify-source

I have been adding some "compilation flags" to activate security measures in my binary. And then I check that the measures are implemented using the *checksec* tool. I have been able to activate all of them except for **FORTIFY**.

I keep geting

> FORTIFY = No,
> Fortified = 0,
> Fortifiable = 4

as output from *checksec* even after compiling with **-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2**

I have to say that I use a common *CMakeLists.txt* for many binaries and I added the **-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2** in the global *add_compile_options* section.

For all the other generated binaries the macro has the expected behavior, that is, the other binaries get "fortified".

I am using **gcc 9.3.0**, my application is written in **c++17** and I compile with **-O2**.

Does someone have an idea why my binary is not getting fortified?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Fortification done by [checksec](https://github.com/slimm609/checksec.sh/blob/master/checksec) script is done heuristically: by grepping for `_chk` symbols in output of `readelf --dyn-syms`. So it will only be able to detect fortification if

- your source code contains calls to fortified functions (`memset`, `memcpy`, etc.)
- code has been compiled with optimizations (macro `__OPTIMIZE__` is defined and greater than zero)
- GCC hasn't optimized them to unchecked versions or explicit loops (see e.g. `gimple_fold_builtin_memory_chk` in [gimple-fold.c](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/gimple-fold.c))

To identify the exact cause of your particular case we'll need an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).