# D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 flag usage not gets effect

Tags: gcc, compilation, fortify-source

As per the document https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/enhance-application-security-fortifysource, I see that `D_FORTIFY_SOURCE` provides buffer overflow checks for the following functions: memcpy, mempcpy, memmove, strcpy,memset ...etc And my source code below has the usage of the function `strcpy` and i try to compiler my code with `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1`where it has no effect in compilation.

test.c:-

```
// fortify_test.c
#include<stdio.h>

/* Commenting out or not using the string.h header will cause this
 * program to use the unprotected strcpy function.
 */
//#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
char buffer[5];
printf ("Buffer Contains: %s , Size Of Buffer is %d\n",
                               buffer,sizeof(buffer));
strcpy(buffer,argv[1]);
printf ("Buffer Contains: %s , Size Of Buffer is %d\n",
                               buffer,sizeof(buffer));
}
```

Compile command:- `gcc -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -g -O2 test.c -o ftest`

I am using `checksec` (https://github.com/slimm609/checksec.sh/blob/master/checksec) tool to verify my created binary as follows:

```
./checksec --file=test
    RELRO           STACK CANARY      NX            PIE             RPATH      RUNPATH      Symbols         FORTIFY Fortified       Fortifiable     FILE
    Full RELRO      Canary found      NX enabled    PIE enabled     No RPATH   No RUNPATH   72) Symbols       No    0               2               test
```

Am i missing something here?
When does `D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1` flag gets into effect?
Lets say my source code file dont have any function (`memcpy, mempcpy, memmove, memset, strcpy ...etc`) usages and try to compile the code with `D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1`, Does gcc tries to FORTIFY my code?

Comment: This question is probly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68847068/why-does-d-fortify-source-2-has-no-effect-in-my-compilation/68858876#68858876

Comment: So not all libraries gets fortifyed right ? If i am not wrong, Only if it satisfies specific conditions like having strcpy...etc function code. Then only D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 gets affected right? But in my code above i am using `strcpy` function right? Do we have any official gcc document about D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 ?

Comment: You are right, I missed the `strcpy` call. Please check my comment, fortification will not work unless you include standard Glibc headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All fortification logic is implemented in Glibc headers. Roughly they contain code which replaces standard APIs (like `strcpy`) with their fortified analogs (like `__strcpy_chk`):

```
$ cat /usr/include/string.h
...
#ifdef _FORTIFY_SOURCE
#define strcpy __strcpy_chk
#endif
...
```

You commented out `string.h` so functions that are defined in this header could not be fortified.

Comment: Thanks @yugr, Do we have any official gcc document that has more info on `D_FORTIFY_SOURCE`. Unfortunately, I don't find it. Also what all comes under Glibc ?

Comment: @kiran Unfortunately to my knowledge such document does not exist. I've just read the Glibc headers to understand the details of implementation.

Comment: Is it mandatory to compile with optimized flags (-O) while using `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE` ?

Comment: @Kiran yes, see how `__USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL` in /usr/include/features.h is defined in non-zero value only if `__OPTIMIZE__ > 0`.